# Using TimeZoneNames: why does Europe/Jersey with languagecode "en-US" return GMT in all the localTimeZoneName fields?

Tags: c#, timezone

I'm trying to get the specific time zones of countries at different moments. So far, the library [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneNames) have helped me, but I have encountered a problem. When I'm trying to get the time zone abbreviations for Jersey and Isle of Man, they both return "GMT" no matter the time of year. I'm using the language code "en-US" and my code is as followed:

```
GetTimeZoneAbbreviation(ZonedDateTime localTimeZone)
{
   string lang = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Name;
   string tzid = localTimeZone.Zone.Id;
   var isDST = localTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime();
   TimeZoneValues localTimeZoneName = TZNames.GetAbbreviationsForTimeZone(tzid, lang);
   return isDST ? localTimeZoneName.Daylight : localTimeZoneName.Standard;
}
```

When debugging, I can see that the localTimeZoneName contains "GMT" in all its fields, where it would normally have "BST" in the field for daylight saving.

I have tried many different countries, but of those I have tried it seems that these two are the only ones not having different values depending on summer/winter time.

**What I have found:**

Looking through the data from the library [data.json](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneNames/blob/main/src/TimeZoneNames/data.json.gz), it seems like the amount of references to Europe/Jersey and Europe/Isle_of_Man is lower than what other countries have, and one of the values is GMT, where others have a pointer to "Europe_Central" or more pointers throughout the data file.

Likewise, the metaZones.xml found in [core](https://unicode.org/Public/cldr/39/core.zip)/common/supplemental also seems to only have a connection between Jersey/Ilse_of_Man and GMT. Other countries such as Dublin have the following:

```
<timezone type="Europe/Dublin">
            <usesMetazone mzone="Irish" to="1971-10-31 02:00"/>
            <usesMetazone mzone="GMT" from="1971-10-31 02:00"/>
</timezone>
...
<mapZone other="GMT" territory="IE" type="Europe/Dublin"/>
...
<mapZone other="Irish" territory="001" type="Europe/Dublin"/>
```

Whereas Jersey and Isle_of_Man only have the timezone.